# determine which child class is calling parent class' method

Tags: php

```
class parent
{
    public function methodInParentClass()
    {
        echo "In parent class called from child class of:";
    }
}

class childOne extends parent
{
    public $childProperty = "in childOne property";
}

class childTwo extends parent
{
    public $childProperty = "in childTwo property";
}
```

Alright, so we have 2 child classes both extending a parent class.  Now, if I call

```
childTwo->methodInParentClass()
```

Questions:

1) How can methodInParentClass determine which class is calling it?  Please note: passing in the name via variable is not available.

2) If #1 is achievable, how can I call the child's class property?  I could instantiate a new class and then call it from that, but wouldn't there be some performance issues with that (especially since my project could be doing this a LOT)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question, actually, have little sense. Let me explain:

1) Yes, you can determine current class with `get_class($this)` called in parent method:

```
 public function methodInParentClass()
 {
     echo "In parent class called from child class of:".get_class($this);
 }
```

2) (Here is why I doubt about the sense). Note, that when calling some method, for example, as you've posted `$childTwo->methodInParentClass()`, where `$childTwo` is instance of class `childTwo` - you will do that with `childTwo` context. Thus, all "child" properties will be properties of **current instance**, i.e. accessible via `$this` variable.

Comment: hmmm... I misread the documentation for get_class and was under the impression it would return the "parent" class / properties.  My bad.